# [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes

What does mean this line during serialization?

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class classname
{
}
```

xsd.exe generates this for all classes. I read documentation, but still can't understand how it affects me if I remove this line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It lets the compiler know whether or not to name the resulting XSD elements or make them anonymous

[XMLSchema](http://xml.coverpages.org/radiya-XMLSchema.pdf)

Elements with attributes must have a complex type

Now, try adding the attribute currency to the simple element price from Listing 7. You can't. An element of a simple type cannot have an attribute. If you want to add an attribute, you must define price as a complex type. In the example in Listing 8, we have defined what is called an **anonymous** type, where no explicit name is given to the complex type. In other words, the name attribute of the complexType element is not defined.

[Microsoft Anonymous Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.anonymoustype.aspx)

Comment: This answer refers to a broken link on ibm.com. The content that was available originally at that URL seems to be available in http://xml.coverpages.org/radiya-XMLSchema.pdf.